# History of Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Folland's book and just went through Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem. As far as I browsed these are two separate theorems and Folland did them together for the sake of compactness.Is this true?

And most importantly, i can see how is Radon-Nikodym theorem important. But can anyone explain the siginificance of  lebesgue decomposition theorem and it's  developmental history.?

Comment: Lebesgue decomposition describes all measures, i.e. they are all the sum of an absolutely continuous, pure point, and absolute singular measure, there're no other variants.